# Issue with FB "Like" button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I am facing an issue with FB "Like" button. I used below code to add "Like" functionality to my page. I used Object Id of the post in href (see below code)

```
<fb:like href="PAGEID_240688205986585" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="450" action="like" colorscheme="light" />
```

But Once I click Like button the post will get liked on FB but the **Post To Facebook** prompt comes with below message **You like PAGEID_240688205986585**. The URL is an invalid URL.

Any thoughts on this issue????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `href` should be a webpage e.g. http://www.stackoverflow.com.  Facebook doesn't understand what `PAGE_ID_240688205986585` is, as its not a valid URL.  Enter your website as the `href` parameter and it will work.

For more information about the Facebook `Like` button, see their [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Comment: How can I use FBML for liking a post from my website? The posts are fetched from the my facebook fan page. The visitors of my website must be able to like these posts from my website also. That's the purpose. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't, you need to use the API to like posts on behalf of a user -the like button is only applicable to liking URLs (and facebook pages)

Comment: Using the above FBML code I can Like the posts,but the issue is with Post To Facebook feature. Is there any-other method to do this?

Comment: Hi I tried using this url http://www.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts/241900295865376 instead of object id, but when I click Like button it is throwing an Error "The page cannot be reached". Any thoughts???

Comment: Thanks to Neil and lgy for their valuable advise.